# Flask checkboxes and textboxes issue

Tags: python, html, flask

I am creating a flask form which requires login, and after login it goes to the entry form where we have check boxes and text entry.

I am facing a specific problem: I am unable to get the value of text boxes but getting the value of checkboxes.

I using flask and using every request method to print my text boxes but not getting the values.

below is my code for main file:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
import os
from flask import redirect, url_for, request
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
app = Flask(__name__)

app.config["SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI"]="sqlite:////OtrsSummary.db"
app.config["SECRET_KEY"]="thisiskey"

db = SQLAlchemy(app)

# @app.route("/ndex")
# def home():
#     names = os.getlogin().split(".")[0].title()
#     return render_template("index.html", name=names)

@app.route("/welcome", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def welcome():
    if request.method=="POST":
        try:
            phase = request.form.get("phase")
            rphase = phase.replace("on", "1")
            print(rphase)
            sale = request.form.get("sale")
            rsale = sale.replace("on", "1")
            print(rsale)
            floor = request.form.get("floor")
            rfloor = floor.replace("on", "1")
            options = request.form.get("options")
            roptions = options.replace("on", "1")
            image = request.form.get("image")
            rimage = image.replace("on", "1")
            video = request.form.get("video")
            rvideo = video.replace("on", "1")
            possession = request.form.get("possession")
            rpossession = possession.replace("on", "1")
            amenities = request.form.get("amenities")
            ramenities = amenities.replace("on", "1")
            prdeactivation = request.form.get("prdeactivation")
            rprdeactivation = prdeactivation.replace("on", "1")
            np = request.form.get("np")
            rnp = np.replace("on", "1")
            newbooking = request.form.get("newbooking")
            rnewbooking = newbooking.replace("on", "1")
            bank = request.form.get("bank")
            rbank = bank.replace("on", "1")
            lat = request.form.get("lat")
            rlat = lat.replace("on", "1")
            usp = request.form.get("usp")
            rusp = usp.replace("on", "1")
            fact = request.form.get("fact")
            rfact = fact.replace("on", "1")
            prname = request.form.get("prname")
            rprname = prname.replace("on", "1")
            prdescription = request.form.get("prdescription")
            rprdescription = prdescription.replace("on", "1")
            prspecification = request.form.get("prspecification")
            rprspecification = prspecification.replace("on", "1")
            builderdetails = request.form.get("builderdetails")
            rbuilerdetails = builderdetails.replace("on", "1")
            tco = request.form.get("tco")
            rtco = tco.replace("on", "1")
            npdeactivation = request.form.get("npdeactivation")
            rnpdeactivation = npdeactivation.replace("on", "1")
            constuctionimages = request.form.get("constuctionimages")
            rconstuctionimages = constuctionimages.replace("on", "1")
            brochure = request.form.get("brochure")
            rbrochure = brochure.replace("on", "1")
            rera = request.form.get("rera")
            rrera = rera.replace("on", "1")
            rticketnumber = request.form["ticketnumber"]##here not getting the value
            rxidnumber = request.form["xidnumber"]##here not getting the value
            rreranumber = request.form["reranumber"]##here not getting the value
            print(rxidnumber)
            print(rticketnumber)
            msg = "Entry Submitted Successfully"

        except AttributeError:
            msg = "Please Do Not Submit Blank Form"
         #con.close()



    return render_template("same.html")

@app.route("/", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def log():
    names = os.getlogin().split(".")[0].title()
    error= None
    if request.method == "POST":
        if request.form["username"]!= os.getlogin() or request.form["password"]!="1234":
            error = "Invalid Credentials.Please Try again."
        else:
            return redirect(url_for("welcome"))
    return render_template("index.html", error=error, name=names)

app.run(debug=True)
```

This is my html:

```
<!doctype <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <title>Page Title</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="main.css" /> -->
        <!-- <script src="main.js"></script> -->
    </head>

    <body>
        <form action="" ALIGN="CENTRE" method="POST">
            <h3>OTRS Basic Information form</h3>
            <TABLE>
                <TR>
                    <TD>
                        Phases and Tower</TD>
                    <TD>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="phase">
                    </TD>
                    <TD>
                        Saleable Mapping </TD>
                    <TD>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="sale">
                    </TD>
                </TR>
                <TR>
                    <TD>
                        Floor Plan </TD>
                    <TD>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="floor">
                    </TD>
                    <TD>
                        Options </TD>
                    <TD>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="options">
                    </TD>
                </TR>
                <TR>
                    <TD>
                        Images </TD>
                    <TD>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="image">
                    </TD>
                    <TD>
                        Video </TD>
                    <TD>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="video">
                    </TD>
                </TR>
                <TR>
                    <TD>
                        Possession Status/Date </TD>
                    <TD>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="possession">
                    </TD>
                    <TD>
                        Amenities </TD>
                    <TD>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="amenities">
                    </TD>
                </TR>
                <TR>
                    <TD>
                        Project Deactivation </TD>
                    <TD>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="prdeactivation">
                    </TD>
                    <TD>
                        Np Slot Changes/Refresh </TD>
                    <TD>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="np">
                    </TD>
                </TR>
                <TR>
                    <TD>
                        New Booking/Resale Lock </TD>
                    <TD>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="newbooking">
                    </TD>
                    <TD>
                        Bank
                    </TD>
                    <TD>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="bank">
                    </TD>
                </TR>
                <TR>
                    <TD>
                        Lat Long/Location </TD>
                    <TD>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="lat">
                    </TD>
                    <TD>
                        USP </TD>
                    <TD>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="usp">
                    </TD>
                </TR>
                <TR>
                    <TD>
                        Fact Table </TD>
                    <TD>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="fact">
                    </TD>
                    <TD>
                        Project Name </TD>
                    <TD>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="prname">
                    </TD>
                </TR>
                <TR>
                    <TD>
                        Project Description </TD>
                    <TD>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="prdescription">
                    </TD>
                    <TD>
                        Project Specification </TD>
                    <TD>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="prspecification">
                    </TD>
                </TR>
                <TR>
                    <TD>
                        Builder Details </TD>
                    <TD>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="builderdetails">
                    </TD>
                    <TD>
                        TCO/Payment Plan</TD>
                    <TD>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="tco">
                    </TD>
                </TR>
                <TR>
                    <TD>
                        NP Deactivation </TD>
                    <TD>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="npdeactivation">
                    </TD>
                    <TD>
                        Construction Images </TD>
                    <TD>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="constuctionimages">
                    </TD>
                </TR>
                <TR>
                    <TD>
                        Brochure </TD>
                    <TD>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="brochure">
                    </TD>
                    <TD>
                        Rera Available </TD>
                    <TD>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="rera">
                    </TD>
                </TR>
                <TR>
                    <TD>
                        Ticket Number </TD>
                    <TD><input type="text" name="ticketnumber">
                    </TD>
                    <TD>
                        XID Number </TD>
                    <TD>
                        <input type="text" name="xidnumber">
                    </TD>
                    <TD>
                        Rera Number </TD>
                    <TD>
                        <input type="text" name="reranumber">
                    </TD>
            </TABLE>
            <input type="submit" value="submit"><br>{{msg}}
        </form>
    </body>

</html>
```

Can anyone please suggest some solutions?

Comment: is there any reason you are not following best-practices of using Flask-WTF (and wtforms)? If you throw an error in debug mode, the flask console will let you introspect the stack (and the state of all your variables)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I tried running your code and I'll get the values of textbox only if all the above checkbox  is checked.

Actually you are catching the attribute exception but not handling it properly.In your code if any of the checkbox goes unchecked it'll give the exception **'NoneType' object has no attribute 'replace**'.which is not handled and because of that it will not execute the next lines of code.

My suggestion on working with checkbox is make a hidden type with same name and value='off' so if it is unchecked it'll give the off value.

```
<input type='hidden' name="checkbox_name" value="off">
```

Answer (score 0):

**request.form** is a dictionary, so you can check if your checkbox has been checked like this:

```
sale = 'checked' if 'sale' in request.form else 'not_checked'
```